# Converting Character to Int in R for Gampminder Dataset

Tags: r

Apologies, I am a relative newbie to R. I am currently trying to analyse data from the Co2 emissions dataset from GapMinder. For values with several 000's, it truncates to k or for several 1000 000's it defaults to m.

For example 714k or 1.5m. This means the dataset defaults to characters and thus cannot run certain numerical analysis.

I am hoping to get a pointer / direction on how to approach this kind of issue? And advice on any wrangling techniques applicable when encountering issues.

I presume there is a form of find replace function that can transform values by referencing specific keys such as k or m.

Apologies if this is a dumb q. Still very new.

Cheers,
Liam

Comment: Hi lb7! Welcome to SO! How to do it depends on the format of the data. To aid better  answers that helps you out, please provide a minimal reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ps. Not a dumb question nor problem! It just need a bit of polishing to fit SO.

Comment: Thanks Harre! Greatly appreciate the feedback both for the question posed and steps to best engaged the community. This area is a little daunting, but hopefully get more confident over time!